# Google Image Search View Image Redirect

Tags: google, redirects, images, search

If you Google `site:fansshare.com`, select an image then click "View image" you won't go directly to the image ex: `http://www.fansshare.com/image.jpg`. Instead, they have it setup so you are redirected to the webpage the image is from. How are they doing that? I want that for my own website.

I found an old WordPress plug-in from 6 years ago called Google Breakdance but of course it doesn't work.

I used to have an old JavaScript script I would paste in the header and it would do the same thing but I found it and dusted it off and it doesn't work at least for WordPress anymore.

Answer (score 2):

They appear to be doing some User-Agent *sniffing* and serving the image to Googlebot (which helps it get indexed) - this may even be a lower resolution version than the one displayed on the page. (However, not sure of the legitimacy of this? It feels like *cloaking*.)

However, any normal user that requests that particular image URL gets (307 temporarily) redirected to a web page that contains what looks like the same image. Although the image displayed on the page is a slightly different URL (served from their CDN by the looks). Like you say, the user is redirected - this is pretty much just a standard 1-1 URL redirect.

That would seem to be the basic principle used here.